# Problem Connecting to MySQL Database on Production Server

Tags: php, mysql

I put my files on my server, but I'm unable to connect to the database. My project works on my local machine, but not on my production server.

I'm using mysql and php.

I'm getting this error:

```
[01-Nov-2010 18:27:01] PHP Warning:  mysql_connect() [<a href='function.mysql-connect'>function.mysql-connect</a>]: Access denied for user 'dbuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /home/mysite/public_html/zendamf_remote_quiz/MyData.php on line 20
[01-Nov-2010 18:27:01] PHP Warning:  mysql_select_db() [<a href='function.mysql-select-db'>function.mysql-select-db</a>]: Access denied for user 'mysite'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/mysite/public_html/zendamf_remote_quiz/MyData.php on line 21
[01-Nov-2010 18:27:01] PHP Warning:  mysql_select_db() [<a href='function.mysql-select-db'>function.mysql-select-db</a>]: A link to the server could not be established in /home/mysite/public_html/zendamf_remote_quiz/MyData.php on line 21
[01-Nov-2010 18:27:01] PHP Warning:  mysql_query() [<a href='function.mysql-query'>function.mysql-query</a>]: Access denied for user 'mysite'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/mysite/public_html/zendamf_remote_quiz/MyData.php on line 28
[01-Nov-2010 18:27:01] PHP Warning:  mysql_query() [<a href='function.mysql-query'>function.mysql-query</a>]: A link to the server could not be established in /home/mysite/public_html/zendamf_remote_quiz/MyData.php on line 28
[01-Nov-2010 18:27:01] PHP Warning:  mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/mysite/public_html/zendamf_remote_quiz/MyData.php on line 31
[01-Nov-2010 18:27:01] PHP Warning:  mysql_free_result(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/mysite/public_html/zendamf_remote_quiz/MyData.php on line 46
```

Does this error mean that my password is incorrect? Any suggestions?

Thank you.

-Laxmidi

Comment: Yup, that's what it means in most cases.

Comment: Is your webserver on a shared resource? If so localhost may not be the host for your database connection.

Comment: Thanks, Pekka. You were right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the help. I made a dumb error. My host prefaces the user name and the database name with the site's user name in order to avoid conflicts. I forgot about that.

Answer (score 1):

Either your user or password is wrong (or even your server, but that's more rare).

Comment: Or, possibly, that user/pass combo is correct, but not for localhost.  It may be a user created for a particular external host.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that there are two users on that stacktrace, 'dbuser' and 'mysite', could be related to that?

Comment: Thanks for the message. I used dbuser and mysite as dummy values in order to make my question shorter.